# XCTest - How to check state of HTML checkbox?

Tags: ios, xcode, webview, ui-automation, xctest

I'm writing UI automation tests with XCTest in Xcode 8.3. I can get to the HTML checkboxes in a `UIWebView`, e.g.:

```
self.app.otherElements["webview_id"].switches[@"0"]
```

but how do I check whether the checkbox is currently checked or not? The `.selected` property always returns 0 and I haven't found any other property that seems to fit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `.value` property. For Swift it's type is Any? which is optional to any type. For switches, the value type is String (possibly NSString for Objective-C). So the final test (in Swift) looks like this:

```
XCTAssertEqual(app.switches["0"].value! as! String, "1")
```

Comment: Thanks Michael! I realized that the difference between `switches[@"0"]` and `switches[@"1"]` is what distinguishes between checkbox checked state.